# Adding contextual information to your logging output in Python 2.5

Tags: python, logging

I am using Python 2.5. The Python logging module allows [adding contextual information to your logging output](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output). Is something similar possible in Python 2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rip off the source code of `LoggerAdapter` from Python 2.6 and plug it in your own source code to get the exact same functionality. [This is how others do it](https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/7345d0586ea0b606b25e5307aa61da38adccf0cc/celery/utils/compat.py#L292).

Comment: Thank you. I got the example from Python documentation working.